# GraphRequest can't be used when Facebook SDK isn't fully initialized

Tags: react-native, facebook-graph-api, expo

All of a sudden I started getting the following error when I try to sign in with Facebook `Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync` in my app

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Caught exception: GraphRequest can't be used when Facebook SDK isn't fully initialized]
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:155:41 in createErrorFromErrorData
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:104:55 in <unknown>
```

I'm running on expo SDK 34. I couldn't find any reference to this warning anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of the Facebook SDK has changed recently.

Now you need to do `Facebook.initializeAsync('<your facebook app id>')` before calling `Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync`

Docs for expo: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/facebook/

Comment: `Facebook.initializeAsync` exists only in SDK 36. I'm working with SDK 34